# Producing a mesh starting from the discretization of the boundaries

Tags: cgal

I am looking a way to extend my boundary element calculation for liquid drop to incorporate concentration effects of particles like surfactant. For this purpose I would like to use my existing evolving surface mesh algorithm which adjust topology and vertex positions for my needs. I assume it could be possible to generate volume mesh giving triangles and vertices which would constrain interior volume mesh boundary faces as it is done in [Numerical simulation of deformable drops with soluble surfactant: Pair interactions and coalescence in shear flow](http://purl.umn.edu/3850).

Is it possible to make volume mesh with constraints of how boundaries are discretion with CGAL?

Answer (score 0):

The [3D Mesh Generation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3) package provides a way to specify constraints (size, angle,...) on triangles of the domain boundary, in addition to constraints on tetrahedral elements (See [this figure](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html#fig__figureparameters) for an illustration).